# Globally turn debug messages on and off in R?

Tags: r, debugging

I am thinking of something like this:

```
> fx = function(x, y) {
+     if (exists("debugging")) {
+         print(x)
+         print(y)
+     }
+     x+y
+ }
> fx(1, 2)
[1] 3
> debugging = 1
> fx(2, 3)
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 5
```

This way you can write as many debugging messages as you want, and when you want to turn them off, you just

```
rm(debugging)
```

The problem is the variable debugging (or any name that you give it) can be removed or created by any other package anytime, which is hard to control. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: if you've turned `debug` on for a few closures,  you can use `is.debugged(cgwtools:lstype())` to identify all closures in your environment for which `debug` is active, and then run `undebug` on that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option would be to define a `debugging` function in your package:

```
debugging <- local({
   stored.value <- FALSE
   function(bool = NULL)
      if (is.null(bool)) {
         stored.value
      } else {
         stopifnot(is.logical(bool), length(bool) == 1L)
         stored.value <<- bool
      }
})

# default value:
debugging()
# [1] FALSE

# set value
debugging(TRUE)

# check value
debugging()
# [1] TRUE
```

This should solve your concern about "What if I decide to change the package name later?" I suppose.

Answer (score 6):

Use an option.  If `xyz` is the name of your package the debugging code in a typical function would do this:

```
 if (getOption("xyz.debug", FALSE)) { print(x); print(y) }
```

Then outside the package issue this to turn on debugging:

```
 options(xyz.debug = TRUE)
```

or this to turn it off:

```
 options(xyz.debug = FALSE) # or options(xyz.debug = NULL)
```

Its not likely that another package will have an option name prefixed with the name of your package.

The main advantages of this approach are that it does not require any infrastructure other than the `if (...) ...` statements making it quite lightweight and the overhead for using it in the case that debugging is off is just an `if` and a call to `getOption` .

Comment: Cool. What if I decide to change the package name later? Is there a way to infer the package name? This seems to require some kind of preprocessing.

Comment: If there is an `.onLoad` function (see `?.onLoad`) it will be passed the package name as one of its arguments and that could be stored in the package and then additional code could fetch the appropriate option name but really I think this is overkill and if you really do change the package name for the few times that that ever happens just use a decent editor to find and substitute each such occurrence.

Answer (score -1):

Just for the record, here is what I came up with after reading @G.Grothendieck 's answer:

```
dbgexec = function(cmd) {
    command = substitute(cmd)
    if(getOption("mypack.debug", FALSE)) eval(cmd, parent.frame())
    invisible(NULL)
}
```

Example:

```
> x = 1.1111
> dbgexec({message("value of x: "); print(x)})
value of x:
[1] 1.1111
> options(mypack.debug = FALSE)
> dbgexec({message("value of x: "); print(x)})
# nothing done here
```

And an experiment with @flodel's answer:

```
> debugging <- local({
+    stored.value <- FALSE
+    function(bool = NULL)
+       if (is.null(bool)) {
+          stored.value
+       } else {
+          stopifnot(is.logical(bool), length(bool) == 1L)
+          stored.value <<- bool
+       }
+ })
>
>
> dbgexec = function(cmd) {
+     command = substitute(cmd)
+     if(debugging()) eval(cmd, parent.frame())
+     invisible(NULL)
+ }
>
> x = 1; y = 2
> dbgexec({x <- 2; y <- 3; print(x + y)})
> x
[1] 1
> y
[1] 2
> debugging()
[1] FALSE
> debugging(TRUE)
> dbgexec({x <- 2; y <- 3; print(x + y)})
[1] 5
> x
[1] 2
> y
[1] 3
```

Comment: No need for `substitute()` and `eval()` here - you can just rely on regular lazy evaluation.

Comment: Could you give some hints? I still don't have a clue how to do it with lazy evaluation.

Comment: `dbgexec = function(cmd) if(getOption("mypack.debug", FALSE)) cmd`